# How to trigger jQuery validation on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form never seems to get validated; I expect some sort of message when the total of the hours reported in the `<select>` elements doesn't match up with the value in the `#TotalHours` field. Instead nothing happens when I submit the form.

What am I missing here? Could it have anything to do with the fact that the `#TotalHours` field is a read only field (a `<div>` instead of an `<input>`)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("hours", function(value, element) {
    var totalHours = 0;
    $('select').each(function(i, sel) {
      var hours = $(sel).val();
      if (hours != "")
        totalHours += parseFloat(hours);
    });
    var reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#TotalHours").val());
    var difference = abs(totalHours - reportedTotalHours);
    return difference >= 0.25; // discrepacancy must be less than a quarter hour
  });

  $("#TheForm").validate({
    TotalHours: {
      hours: true
    }
  });
});
```

edit: here is a simplified version of my form, with one of the `<select>` tags shown:

```
<form id="TheForm" method="get">
    <input type='hidden' id="xnid" name="xnid" value="f/PzSJBJ+Gzx9UaI1e3cR2nT/tCbbzkTVCA6uTk6GZ92JhJLXpp65QvIWZ48wEKGrYQy8CWLE0emOlK4fx2TbUcXAo2UPau2RHsXMwzNOIokcNQ5dlD//EmtiMB6XX0o+z6qZp1YaCdn4cYgK8erKbeueu4Ksxco4KdMZDvPDbuUTZYQTJbF8jlMJldUnvMrqvqWB1ZdAcAuFQFoKwq+nkigzEElYp0AoSeM5D+ki8mZ/3Ue3FaHO57tury53E1EQewMgXu08TblQjEMemUW1EwzKXnsP+YGZCGN0hMPN2W7LaCyq5jxy9M8LWvFRNPMO3IRFNeyAXw=" /><input type='hidden' name="EntityID" value="" /><input type='hidden' name="EntityType" /><input type='hidden' name="AssessmentID" value="4435" /><input type='hidden' name="AssessmentTypeID" value="6" /><a name='_0' /><div style="text-align:left;">
<!-- removed a few input fields with identifying information -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.validator.addMethod("hours", function (value, element) {
                    var totalHours = 0;
                    $('select').each(function (i, sel) {
                        var hours = $(sel).val();
                        if (hours != "")
                            totalHours += parseFloat(hours);
                    });
                    var reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#TotalHours").val());
                    var difference = abs(totalHours - reportedTotalHours);
                    return difference >= 0.25; // discrepacancy must be less than a quarter hour
                });

                $("#TheForm").validate({
                    TotalHours: {
                        hours: true
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <a name='_Section1_2' /><div style="text-align:left;">
            <H4>2. Transportation Hours</H4><p></p><div class="jtx-row"><a class="right" style="margin-right:10px;" title="Next" href="#_Section1_3" tabindex="-1">Next</a><div class="right" style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div><a class="right" title="Top" href="#Section1" tabindex="-1">Top</a><div class="right" style="text-align:left;">&nbsp;</div><a class="right" title="Previous" href="#_Section1_1" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></div><div class="jtx-row">
                <div id='__E746-field' class='jtx-field fill90' style="width:300px;"><label for="">Answer</label><select id="__E746" name="E147" class="fill ddl" style="width:300px;" data-scopename=""><option value='' selected='true'></option><option value='721'>0</option><option value='718'>.25</option><option value='719'>.5</option><option value='720'>.75</option><option value='722'>1</option><option value='723'>1.25</option><option value='724'>1.5</option><option value='725'>1.75</option><option value='726'>2</option><option value='727'>2.25</option><option value='728'>2.5</option><option value='729'>2.75</option><option value='730'>3</option><option value='731'>3.25</option><option value='732'>3.5</option><option value='733'>3.75</option><option value='734'>4</option><option value='735'>4.25</option><option value='736'>4.5</option><option value='737'>4.75</option><option value='738'>5</option><option value='919'>5.25</option><option value='920'>5.5</option><option value='921'>5.75</option><option value='922'>6</option><option value='923'>6.25</option><option value='924'>6.5</option><option value='925'>6.75</option><option value='926'>7</option><option value='927'>7.25</option><option value='928'>7.5</option><option value='929'>7.75</option><option value='930'>8</option><option value='931'>8.25</option><option value='932'>8.5</option><option value='933'>8.75</option><option value='934'>9</option><option value='935'>9.25</option><option value='936'>9.5</option><option value='937'>9.75</option><option value='938'>10</option><option value='939'>10.25</option><option value='940'>10.5</option><option value='941'>10.75</option><option value='942'>11</option><option value='943'>11.25</option><option value='944'>11.5</option><option value='945'>11.75</option><option value='946'>12</option></select></div>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $('#__E746').selectmenu({}).selectmenu('menuWidget').css('height', '100px');</script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- more fields like the one above are here -->
</form>
```

and here is my `#TotalHours` `<div>`:

```
<div id='TotalHours' style='border: none;' class='display-field ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'>0.5</div><
```

Comment: If `#TotalHours` is a div as you claim then it won't have a `val()` to read. Try `text()`. You also cannot use `TotalHours` in the `validate()` method (assuming there's no `input` with that name, and you're trying to reference the `div`)

Comment: Can you provide the sample HTML you're running against?

Comment: Hmm, well there is a lot of HTML on this page; I'd need to figure out a way to trim it down to what exactly we need here...

Comment: You can provide the relevant elements (#TheForm, select, etc)

Comment: Just copy it from the source directly, removing any non-essential parts. All we really need to see is the `form`, the relevant `input` within it and the `#TotalHours` div

Comment: OK, I edited my OP to share this code.

Comment: I read that jQuery validation goes by the `name` attribute of the element to validate rather than its `id` so I added a `name` attribute, but no dice. I also tried changing the `<div>` being validate to a text field, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @ekolis Have you tried Rory's suggestion to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`?

Comment: @ChrisG yes I did